# VBA Microsoft word Delete an inserted "new line"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using a VBA for Microsoft word that finds a certain text and replaces it with a text field (IncludeText field). The challenging part is that the inserted text always ends in a new line. I need to modify my code to delete this new line at the end of the inserted text.

Here is my Code:

```
`Sub Macro1()
    ReplaceWithDocVar "Mary", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Templates\\INSERT COMPANY NAME.docx"
End Sub


Sub ReplaceWithDocVar(strFind As String, strVarName As String)
Dim oStory As Range
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With oStory.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchWholeWord:=True)
                oStory.Text = ""
                oStory.Fields.Add Range:=oStory, _
                                  Type:=wdFieldIncludeText, _
                                  Text:=Chr(34) & strVarName & Chr(34), _
                                  PreserveFormatting:=False
                oStory.Collapse 0
            Loop
        End With
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                With oStory.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchWholeWord:=True)
                        oStory.Text = ""
                        oStory.Fields.Add Range:=oStory, _
                                          Type:=wdFieldIncludeText, _
                                          Text:=Chr(34) & strVarName & Chr(34), _
                                          PreserveFormatting:=False
                        oStory.Collapse 0
                Loop
                End With
             Wend
End If
        
    Next oStory
    Set oStory = Nothing
lbl_Exit:

    Exit Sub
End Sub

`
```

Comment: Nothing in your code is directly inserting a new line. Inserting an entire document in the IncludeText field will.

Comment: *If* you control the content of the included .docx, you can try marking its entire text *except the final paragraph mark* with a bookmark, say "includeme", then add that bookmark name as a second parameter in your INCLUDETEXT field.